# Discord bot made using JDA is deleting incorrect messages

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I made a discord bot that reads a specific channel and checks if the users are typing in a specific sintax. If the user doesn’t type using the proper syntax the bot is supposed to delete the message.

Here is the code: [image]

The bot is not supposed to delete messages that start with the prefixes “!,- and ~” or messages from bots.

The bot successfully deletes the improper messages but also deletes the proper messages. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `||` with `&&`. It should be

```java
if (!content.startsWith("!") && !content.startsWith("-") && !content.startsWith("~")) { ... }
```